# What permission do another domain user need to restart IIS app pool on my machine?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, iis, powershell

Can this be done without adding user to local Administrators group? All I need is to remotely stop app pool, create site and start the pool again. I'm trying to do this with Powershell script. I keep getting "A drive with the name 'IIS' does not exist."

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the 'Feature Delegation' or [IIS Remote Management](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc772535(v=ws.10).aspx) to enable users access to this without making them local admins.

Comment: Do I need Active Directory Certificate Services for Remote Management to work?

Comment: No, you can setup local accounts inside of IIS for people so it is totally standalone.